# Suggestions to Process Complex + Large Data File

Tags: objective-c, performance, loops, core-data, bigdata

I have a very large and complex data file (.txt, see snippet below) of about 10MB and would like to know the best way to store it and access it later on.
My app currently uses core data for storage of other entities but I don't see how I can create an entity from this type of data file because of its complexity.

This file is divided as follows:
First line of each major section begins with an A| and means a new 'airway' to be defined. Then, is it's name, so in the example below we have the airway named V320 and another named V321. On the following lines, we have important data, the 'points'/waypoints which make up this airway. Each one has a name, and coordinates. So the first one here is PLN at 45.63N and -84.66W (coordinates). Then, from there the next one is LORIW at 45.35N and -84.92W, from LORIW we go to IROTO, and so on...

NOTE: There may be two, three, maybe even 4 airways with the same 'name' like V320 for example has 3...but each one is in it's own part of the map.

The other values there are irrelevant such as the numbers after the coordinate pair.

In essence, I need all this so that I can then draw lines on my map (GMSPolyLine using Google map SDK) which goes through all these points for each airway and then to create GMSMarkers(google version of MKAnnotation) for each waypoint which the user can tap.
I can handle the drawing of lines/markers on the map but the difficult part for me to visualize is the manipulation of this data and making it easier to access.

Let me know if you have any questions.

```
A|V320|20
S|PLN|045630647|-0084664108|LORIW|045352072|-0084924214|0|219|1998
S|LORIW|045352072|-0084924214|IROTO|045188989|-0085075111|219|219|1168
S|IROTO|045188989|-0085075111|ADENO|045030644|-0085220425|219|219|1132
S|ADENO|045030644|-0085220425|TIDDU|044877978|-0085359767|215|215|1090
S|TIDDU|044877978|-0085359767|SKIPR|044831714|-0085401772|215|215|330
.....

A|V321|29
S|PZD|031655206|-0084293100|KUTVE|031866950|-0084451303|0|329|1505
S|KUTVE|031866950|-0084451303|DUVAT|031948772|-0084512695|329|329|582
S|DUVAT|031948772|-0084512695|LUMPP|032041158|-0084582139|329|329|657
S|LUMPP|032041158|-0084582139|PREST|032176375|-0084684117|329|329|963
S|PREST|032176375|-0084684117|CSG|032615253|-0085017631|326|326|3129
S|CSG|032615253|-0085017631|JALVO|032722436|-0085064033|326|339|684
.....
```

Answer (score 1):

Your data exhibits some regularity. If it is predictable and consistent, just write a parser that iterates through the file and creates appropriate Core Data entities.

For example, the fact that each new airway is separated by a newline can help you find those. Also, each final waypoint is repeated in the next line unless you are at the end of an airway record. I think you can do this in maybe 20-30 lines of code.

On your development machine (or even on an iPad or recent iPhone, for that matter), even creating a 10MB array in memory (to be parsed) should not be a constraint.

If the data is static, you can use the resulting sqlite database as a read-only persistent store that you can include in your app bundle.

As for the parser, it would be something like this:

```
NSString *file = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:fileURLString 
                 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

NSArray *lines = [file componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
for (NSString *line in lines) {
    if (line.length < 1) { continue; }
    NSArray *fields = [line componentsSeparatedByString:@"|"];
    if ([fields.firstObject isEqualToString:@"A"]) {
        // insert new airway object and populate with other fields
    }
    else if ([fields.firstObject isEqualToString:@"S"]) {
        // insert new waypoint object (two for each first line)
        // assign as relationship to the current airway
        // and to another waypoint as necessary
    }
}
[managedObjectContext save:nil];
```

Comment: I already include a default sqlite database in my app bundle to be copied over to documents on first run, speeds things up. However, I am still kind of fuzzy on how to write this parser... Still relatively new to this type of work in Obj C.

Comment: Thanks for the code snippet. Ok, I understand now how to process the file, but what type of entities would I create in the Core Data xcdatamodel? It would ned to be an array that I store in each entity of an 'airway' containing all the waypoints?

Comment: You have a to-many relationship from Airway to Waypoint. Please file a separate question for your data model, as this is quite a distinct problem. You should accept this answer first.